# Duplicated and unnecessary joins when using Linq in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Basically I crossed the same problem of Linq provider in this [linq-to-nhibernate-produces-unnecessary-joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291616/linq-to-nhibernate-produces-unnecessary-joins)

```
List<Competitions> dtoCompetitions;
dtoCompetitions = (from compset in session.Query<FWBCompetitionSet>()
                    where compset.HeadLine == true 
                    && compset.A.B.CurrentSeason == true
                   select (new Competitions
                           {
                                       CompetitionSetID = compset.CompetitionSetID,
                                       Name = compset.Name,
                                       Description = compset.Description,
                                       Area = compset.Area,
                                       Type = compset.Type,
                                       CurrentSeason = compset.A.B.CurrentSeason,
                                       StartDate = compset.StartDate
                            }
                    )).ToList();
```

Which leads to duplicated join in its generated SQL

```
SELECT fwbcompeti0_.competitionsetid AS col_0_0_,
   fwbcompeti0_.name             AS col_1_0_,
   fwbcompeti0_.DESCRIPTION      AS col_2_0_,
   fwbcompeti0_.area             AS col_3_0_,
   fwbcompeti0_.TYPE             AS col_4_0_,
   fwbseason3_.currentseason     AS col_5_0_,
   fwbcompeti0_.startdate        AS col_6_0_
FROM   fwbcompetitionset fwbcompeti0_
       INNER JOIN A fwbcompeti1_
         ON fwbcompeti0_.competitionseasonid = fwbcompeti1_.competitionseasonid
       INNER JOIN A fwbcompeti2_
         ON fwbcompeti0_.competitionseasonid = fwbcompeti2_.competitionseasonid
       INNER JOIN B fwbseason3_
         ON fwbcompeti2_.seasonid = fwbseason3_.seasonid
WHERE  fwbcompeti0_.headline = @p0
       AND fwbseason3_.currentseason = @p1
```

Notice these joins, which are totally duplicated and also affect my SQL Server's performence.

```
       INNER JOIN A fwbcompeti1_
         ON fwbcompeti0_.competitionseasonid = fwbcompeti1_.competitionseasonid
       INNER JOIN A fwbcompeti2_
         ON fwbcompeti0_.competitionseasonid = fwbcompeti2_.competitionseasonid
```

**Update1**

In the NHibernate 3.2, this LiNQ bug is still valid, and I could not find a simple and reasonable Linq solution.
So I used QueryOver + JoinAlias + TransformUsing finishing the job, workds perfect to me.

```
FWBCompetitionSet compset = null;
FWBCompetitionSeason compseason = null;
FWBSeason season = null;
IList<Competitions> dtoCompetitions;
dtoCompetitions = session.QueryOver<FWBCompetitionSet>(() => compset)
.JoinAlias(() => compset.FWBCompetitionSeason, () => compseason)
.JoinAlias(() => compseason.FWBSeason, () => season)
.Where(() => compset.HeadLine == true)  
.And(() => season.CurrentSeason == true)
.SelectList(
list => list
.Select(c => c.CompetitionSetID).WithAlias(() => compset.CompetitionSetID)
.Select(c => c.Name).WithAlias(() => compset.Name)
.Select(c => c.Description).WithAlias(() => compset.Description)
.Select(c => c.Area).WithAlias(() => compset.Area)
.Select(c => c.Type).WithAlias(() => compset.Type)
.Select(c => season.CurrentSeason).WithAlias(() => season.CurrentSeason)
.Select(c => c.StartDate).WithAlias(() => compset.StartDate)
)
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Competitions>())
.List<Competitions>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yet Another Edit:**

I think I finally found out what's going on. It seems that the LINQ to NHibernate provider has trouble navigating associations from the target to the source table and generates a separate join each time it encounters such an association.

Since you don't provide your mapping, I used the mapping from  [linq-to-nhibernate-produces-unnecessary-joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291616/linq-to-nhibernate-produces-unnecessary-joins). This model has a *Document* with one Job and many *TranslationUnits*. Each *TranslationUnit* has many *Translation* entities.

When you try to find a Translation based on a Job, you are traversing the associations in the reverse order and the LINQ provider generates multiple joins: one for Translation -> TranslationUnit and one for TranslationUnit to Document.

This query will generate redundant joins:

```
session.Query<TmTranslation>()
          .Where(x => x.TranslationUnit.Document.Job == job)
          .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
          .ToList();
```

If you reverse the navigation order to Document -> TranslationUnit -> Translation, you get a query that doesn't produce any redundant joins:

```
var items=(from doc in session.Query<Document>()
        from tu in doc.TranslationUnits
            from translation in tu.Translations
       where doc.Job ==job                        
       orderby translation.Id
       select translation).ToList();
```

Given this quirkiness, QueryOver seems like a better option.

**Previous Edit:**

I suspect the culprit is *compset.A.B.CurrentSeason*. The first joined table (fwbcompeti1_) returns **A**.B while the next two (fwbcompeti2_ and fwbseason3_) are used to return A.**B**. The LINQ to NHibernate provider doesn't seem to guess that A is not used anywhere else and fails to remove it from the generated statement.

Try to help the optimizer a little by replacing *CurrentSeason = compset.A.B.CurrentSeason* with *CurrentSeason = **true***  from the *select*, since your where statement returns only items with CurrentSeason == true.

**EDIT:** What I mean is to change the query like this:

```
List<Competitions> dtoCompetitions;
dtoCompetitions = (from compset in session.Query<FWBCompetitionSet>()
                   where compset.HeadLine == true 
                   && compset.A.B.CurrentSeason == true
                   select (new Competitions
                       {
                                   CompetitionSetID = compset.CompetitionSetID,
                                   Name = compset.Name,
                                   Description = compset.Description,
                                   Area = compset.Area,
                                   Type = compset.Type,
                                   CurrentSeason = true,
                                   StartDate = compset.StartDate
                        }
                )).ToList();
```

I simply replace the value compset.A.B.CurrentSeason with true

Comment: But it will introduce performence issue. Image you originally only need return 2 rows data of current season, by using the alternative solution (CurrentSeason = true from the selec), system will return hundredes rows of data

Comment: Changing what values you return for a specific field in the select part will not change how many rows get returned. What do you mean?

Comment: Thank you Panagiotis, now I got your point and gave it a try . Unfournately, it gave the same SQL. Think I will have to switch to QueryOver API.

Comment: I finally found a way to write the LINQ query that doesn't introduce redundant joins: just write it backwards :P . Check the edit

Comment: Seems like a promising answer, will give it a try later on